# Recover Ubuntu after MBR recreation

Tags: dual-boot, mbr

Initially I had Windows 7. After installing Ubuntu I was not able to boot into Windows.
Therefore I recreated MBR from Windows Repair *bootrect /fixmbr*.

I am not experience in those things therefore I wondered if it is possible to add Ubuntu partition to the MBR so that I can dual-boot betweeen Ubuntu and Win7.

Answer (score 0):

During Ubuntu install, did you choose to have Ubuntu co-exist with other OS? Like Windows? If you can now boot into Windows and as I understand you can, try installing Ubuntu again but carefully select the right option, that is to have Ubuntu co-exist with Windows.

You might already have Linux partitions, since you had Ubuntu at one point in time, so you might want to delete those partitions if no data is there to keep, via the install Wizard, that takes care of the Ubuntu install. This will result in a clean install, for you.

EDIT: Ubuntu by default, I think opts for multi-boot setup. But to restore and not install again, you could try this link: [Grub restore](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repairrestorereinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd/#.UPCyYB56D_s)

Worked for me a few times when Windows 7 re-install changed the bootloader to it's own version.